# Не пойму почему ошибка через раз в обработке

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

Суть задания: 
Удалить строки и столбцы где на пересечении есть "0"

Проблема:
Раз через раз работает, указывает что ошибка в операторе `tmp[i1][j1] = arr[i][j];` И криво работает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int** Memory(int col, int row) {
int **arr = new int*[row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[col];
}
return arr;
}
void Rand(int col, int row, int **arr) {
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}
}
void Print(int col, int row, int **arr) {
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

void DeleteColRow(int **arr, int row, int col) {

int i1 = 0, j1 = col;
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    bool control = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
            control = true;
            index = j;
            break;
        }
        else if (arr[i][j] != 0) {
            control = false;
        }
    }
    if (control == true) {
        j1--;
    }
    else if (control == false) {
        i1++;
    }
}
cout << i1 << endl << j1 << endl;
int **tmp = Memory(j1, i1);
for (int i = 0, i1 = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    bool control = false;
    for (int j = 0, j1 = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
            control = true;
            break;
        }
        if (index != j) {
            if (arr[i][j] != 0) {
                tmp[i1][j1] = arr[i][j];
                j1++;
                control = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (control == false) {
        i1++;
    }
}
Print(j1, i1, tmp);
}


void main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int col = 5;
    int row = 5;
    int **arr = Memory(col, row);
    int **arr2 = Memory(col, row);
    cout << "Delete from zero" << endl;
    cout << "Delete row and col" << endl;
    Rand(col, row, arr);
    Print(col, row, arr);
    cout << endl;
    DeleteColRow(arr, row, col);   //удаление строки и столбца где на      пересечении есть 0
}
```

Comment: А что за ошибка ? Выход за границы массива ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неаккуратны в повторном использовании переменных, из-за чего в данном случае произошла потеря актуальных значений размеров массивов.

Позволю себе дать несколько советов:

- Будьте аккуратнее с выделением массивов в динамической памяти и
  индексами этих массивов;
- Всегда освобождайте выделенную память;
- Привыкайте писать короткие простые функции, делающие ровно одно
  действие.

Исправил ваш код для первой части задания, вторую оставляю вам для самостоятельного решения:

```
using namespace std;

int** AllocArray(int row, int col)
{
  int **arr = new int*[row];
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    arr[i] = new int[col];
  }
  return arr;
}

void FreeArray(int **arr, int row)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    delete[] arr[i];
  }
  delete[] arr;
}

void FillByRand(int **arr, int row, int col)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
  }
}

void PrintArray(int **arr, int row, int col)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

bool RowHasZero(int* arr_row, int col)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    if (arr_row[i] == 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void CopyRow(int* from, int* to, int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    to[i] = from[i];
  }
}

int** DeleteRowHasZero(int **arr, int row, int col, int *result_row)
{
  int tmp[row][col];
  *result_row = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    if (!RowHasZero(arr[i], col)) {
      CopyRow(arr[i], tmp[(*result_row)++], col);
    }
  }

  int **result = AllocArray(*result_row, col);
  for (int i = 0; i < *result_row; i++) {
    CopyRow(tmp[i], result[i], col);
  }

  return result;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  int col = 5;
  int row = 5;
  int **arr = AllocArray(row, col);
  FillByRand(arr, row, col);

  cout << "Delete from zero" << endl;
  PrintArray(arr, row, col);
  cout << endl;
  int without_zero_row = 0;
  int **without_zero = DeleteRowHasZero(arr, row, col, &without_zero_row);   //удаление строк, где есть 0
  PrintArray(without_zero, without_zero_row, col);
  cout << endl;
  FreeArray(without_zero, without_zero_row);

  FreeArray(arr, row);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Предложенное решение - не самое оптимальное, и уж никак не претендует на тег `c++`.  Но для учебной задачи по работе с указателями и динамической памятью полагаю сойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это, не тянет на самое оптимальное решение, но заюзать можно.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

#define AGGRESSIVE 1

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix( size_t, size_t );
    ~Matrix();

public:
    virtual void randomInitialization();
    virtual void excludePartsWithSOSymbol( );

    void outputToScreen();
private:
    T** m_entries;

    size_t m_numRows;
    size_t m_numCols;
};

template <typename T>
inline Matrix<T>::Matrix( size_t rows, size_t cols )
    : m_numRows( rows )
    , m_numCols( cols )
{
    m_entries = new T*[m_numRows];

    for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
    {
        m_entries[i] = new T[m_numCols];
    }
}

template <typename T>
inline Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
{
    if( m_entries != nullptr )
    {
        for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
        {
            delete[] m_entries[i];
        }

        delete[] m_entries;
        m_entries = nullptr;
    }
}

template <typename T>
inline void Matrix<T>::randomInitialization()
{
    std::default_random_engine randEngine;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distributor( 0, 255 );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
    {
        for( size_t j = 0; j < m_numRows; ++j )
        {
            m_entries[i][j] = static_cast<T>(distributor( randEngine ));
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
inline void Matrix<T>::excludePartsWithSOSymbol()
{
    int * rFlags = new int[m_numRows];
    memset( rFlags, 1, m_numRows * sizeof( int ) );

    int * cFlags = new int[m_numCols];
    memset( rFlags, 1, m_numCols * sizeof( int ) );

    std::vector<T> acceptSymbols;

#ifdef AGGRESSIVE
    m_entries[2][2] = 0;
    m_entries[3][4] = 0;
#endif

    for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
    {
        for( size_t j = 0; j < m_numRows; ++j )
        {
            if( static_cast<int>(m_entries[i][j]) == 0 )
            {
                rFlags[i] = 0;
                cFlags[j] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                acceptSymbols.push_back( m_entries[i][j] );
            }
        }
    }

    size_t rCounter = 0U, cCounter = 0U;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
    {
        if( rFlags[i] != 0 )
            ++rCounter;
    }


    if( rCounter == 0 )
    {
        delete[] cFlags;
        delete[] rFlags;

        /* no null-entrie */

        return;
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numCols; ++i )
    {
        if( cFlags[i] != 0 )
            ++cCounter;
    }


    if( m_entries != nullptr )
    {
        for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
        {
            delete[] m_entries[i];
        }

        delete[] m_entries;
    }

    m_numRows = rCounter;
    m_numCols = cCounter;

    m_entries = new T*[m_numRows];

    for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
    {
        m_entries[i] = new T[m_numCols];

        for( size_t j = 0; j < m_numCols; ++j )
        {
            m_entries[i][j] = acceptSymbols.at( i + j );
        }
    }

}

template<typename T>
inline void Matrix<T>::outputToScreen()
{
    std::cout << "\n\nOuput:\n\n";

    for( size_t i = 0; i < m_numRows; ++i )
    {
        for( size_t j = 0; j < m_numCols; ++j )
        {
            std::cout << m_entries[i][j] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> mrx = Matrix<int>( 10, 10 );

    mrx.randomInitialization();
    mrx.outputToScreen();

    mrx.excludePartsWithSOSymbol();
    mrx.outputToScreen();

    std::system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```